# Where clause with arrays in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query a list of documents in Firestore where a certain array actually has values

Here's my attempt at checking if the array has any values

```
query = db.collection("CollectionName")
                .whereField("TheArray", isGreaterThan: [])
```

I then get the error

> "Queries with inequality on array values are not supported."

If it's not supported, is there any possible way for me to check if the array has any values?

EDIT: The array can exist as an empty array

Comment: I don't think that is supported. Maybe you can maintain a count as a workaround?

Comment: Ya, it's a fairly dynamic array. So it's the debate between that or just doing it client side. But it would be nice if I could do it server side without a count

Comment: Do you have cloud functions set up? Would be fairly simple to add as a function

Comment: No I don't, I'll read the docs now!

Comment: Sure - just shout out for help if you need any. This repo is awesome to get started: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples. I have multiple small functions that I view as "adding small feature until firestore will support it eventually" :) Just like your question. Just remember that if you create a trigger based update function, on the same document, that you don't create a recursion hell. (It's simple to avoid, but yeah, read the documentation :) )